# How to stop Marketing Cloud from canceling activities if one single email send fails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send

I discovered the problem that Journey Builder Send Email activities are somehow cancelled (I guess the trigger for that was an error like not being able to attach a file from the enhanced ftp). The strange thing is, the status remains *Running*, but all subsequent emails are only *Queued* and not sent.

When configuring a triggered send manually there is the possibility to set an error threshold (so calls to this triggered send via api are disabled after a certain amount of errors), which isn't available in the Send Email activity in Journey Builder. Just until recently the Journey Builder triggered sends seem to slowly disappear from Email Studio so they may not be editable manually anymore. The following messages are shown in Email Studio:

> Journey Builder Sends is scheduled for retirement in Email Studio in an upcoming release. Until then, you can only view the Triggered Sends associated with their Journeys. All edits can be made directly inside Journey Builder, through the Email Activity.
>
> All triggered send edits can be made directly inside the Journey Builder Send Email activity. Pausing triggered sends here does not pause a contact's progression through the Journey.

Hundreds of customers not receiving important transactional emails because one attachment for a single customer failed is a huge problem!

- Is there a solution for this?
- Is there any setting that tells Marketing Cloud to not cancel/pause and queue the subsequent sends, but rather just continue to send the messages?

*Additional Info: I already logged a case for this, but I guess someone might have discovered this earlier and has a fix for this.*

**tl;dr:** If one single email send fails, the corresponding Journey Builder Send Email activity (or rather triggered send) is paused without being displayed as paused. How can this be circumvented so subsequent emails are sent instead of being queued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out this seems to be another feature/setting that isn't activated by default and has to be requested as a support case. So even if you see this feature in Email Studio when configuring triggered sends, you need separate activation for use within Journey Builder.

> **Error Threshold**
> *A configurable limit that stops a send job when a designated number of errors occur.*
> This option helps prevent a single error from stopping the entire job. **Contact your Salesforce Marketing Cloud relationship manager for more information.**
> (Source: [Configure the Send Email Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/configuring_the_send_email_activity/configure_the_send_email_activity/))

If the feature is activated there is a global threshold setting defined by support, that can be activated or deactivated in the send email activity via a checkbox. To be more flexible a user defined threshold on a per activity basis would make sense. Therefore I posted this on IdeaExchange. If you like the idea, please vote for it: [User defineable Error Threshold in Journey Builder send email activity.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003UB5QAM)

Comment: That's pretty priceless if the setting's been' exposed in Journey Builder - they've obviously stopped you getting to the Triggered Send Definition. Have you got support to do this for a customer and can see it? It looks like it may be a settable property of the TSD SOAP object, so maybe we can set even if it isn't available in the UI.